# How to find $ h : \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R} $ measurable such that : $ f = h \circ g $?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ ( \Omega_1 , \tau_1 ) $ and $ ( \Omega_2 , \tau_2 ) $ be two measurable spaces, and $ f : \Omega_1 \to \mathbb{R} $ and $ g : \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2 $ two measurable maps, and $ \mathbb{R} $ equipped with $ \beta $ as $ \sigma $ - algebra.

How to show that :

- $ f^{-1} ( \beta ) \subset g^{-1} ( \tau_2 ) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \exists h : \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R} $ measurable such that : $ f = h \circ g $

?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean $f^{-1}(\tau_2)\subset g^{-1}(\beta)$? Your current setup does not allow for $f^{-1}:\tau_2 \to \tau_1$ to take subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: And there does not exists exists such an $h: \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h\circ g$ is well-defined. That is the range of $g$ does not coincide with the domain of $h$ which must be true if one would talk about $h \circ g$.

Comment: Sorry ! $ f : \Omega_1 \to \mathbb{R} $ and $ g : \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2 $.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't see why this standard approach, which works if $g:\Omega_1 \to \mathbb{R}$, shouldn't work in this setup.*

Let $(\Omega_1,\tau_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\tau_2)$ be measurable spaces, and assume that $g:\Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ is a $\tau_1/\tau_2$-measurable mapping and $f:\Omega_1\to \mathbb{R}$ is a mapping such that $$f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))=\sigma(f)\subset \sigma(g)=g^{-1}(\tau_2). $$
Since $f:(\Omega_1,\sigma(f))\to  (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is measurable, we know that there exists a sequence of $\sigma(f)$-simple functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging point-wise to $f$. That is $f_n$ is of the form
$$
f_n = \sum_{i=1}^{k(n)} a_{i,n} 1_{A_{i,n}},
$$
with $a_{i,n}  \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A_{i,n} \in \sigma(f)$ for $i=1,...,k(n)$. Since $\sigma(f) \subset \sigma(g)$ we know that for any $A_{i,n}\in \sigma(f)$ there exists a set in $B_{i,n}\in \tau_2$ such that $A_{i,n} = g^{-1}(B_{i,n})$. Now define the measurable mapping $h_n:(\Omega_2,\tau_2) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ by
$$
h_n = \sum_{i=1}^{k(n)} a_{i,n} 1_{B_{i,n}}
$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and note that $f_n=h_n\circ g$. Now let $h$ be the pointwise upper limit of $h_n$ ($h(x)=\limsup_n h_n(x)$ $\forall x\in \Omega_2$), and note that this implies that $h$ is $\tau_2/\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable. For any $x\in \Omega_1$ we have that
$$
f(x)= \limsup_n f_n(x) = \limsup_n h_n (g(x)) = h( g(x)),
$$
proving the existence of a measurable mapping $h:(\Omega_2,\tau_2) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $f=h\circ g$.